# Como fazer para centralizar uma pagina carregada pelo onclick dentro de uma div?

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte formulario que quero carregar dentro de uma div

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.campo {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

fieldset {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.campo input {
  margin: 10px 1%;
  width: 60%;
}

.campo select {
  margin: 10px 1%;
  width: 60%;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

label:after {
    content: ':';
}

legend {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=date],
input[type=email], input[type=password], select {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #008000;
}

input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=reset]:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  margin: -60px;
}

span {
  padding: -5px;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/formstyle.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="form" method="post" action="#">
  <div class="area">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Cadastrar Computadores</legend>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="nome">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome" required>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="status">Status</label>
      <select name="status" id="status" required>
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="#">Habilitado</option>
       <option value="#">Desabilitado</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="fab">Fabricante</label>
      <input type="text" name="fab" id="fab" placeholder="Informe o fabricante">
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="model">Modelo</label>
      <input type="text" name="model" id="model" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="pm">Placa-mãe</label>
      <input type="text" name="pm" id="pm" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="proc">Processador</label>
      <input type="text" name="proc" id="proc" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="ram">RAM</label>
      <input type="number" name="ram" id="ram" placeholder="Informe a qtd em GB" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="hd">HD</label>
      <input type="number" name="hd" id="hd" placeholder="Informe a qtd em GB" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="ssd">Possui SSD?</label>
     <span>Sim</span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ssd" id="ssd" onchange="habilitar()">
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="qtd">Quantidade</label>
      <input type="number" name="qtd" id="qtd" placeholder="Informe a qtd em GB" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="video">Placa de vídeo</label>
      <input type="text" name="video" id="video" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="fonte">Fonte de alimentação</label>
      <input type="text" name="fonte" id="fonte" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="leitor">Driver óptico</label>
      <input type="text" name="leitor" id="leitor" placeholder="Informe o modelo" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="inventario">Nº de inventário</label>
      <input type="number" name="inventario" id="inventario" placeholder="Informe um número" >
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
     <label for="comentarios">Comentários</label>
      <textarea rows="8" cols="60" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    </div>

   </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
   <input type="reset" name="Limpar" value="Limpar" style="margin-right: 15px;">
  </div>
 </form>
<body>
```

Aqui começa o menu que quero carregar o formulario dentro de modo que fique centralizado e sem perder a formatação

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1D2731;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid #0B3C5D;
}


.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 21px;
  background-color: #0B3C5D;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="main_content">

        <div class="header">
          <a href="#">Sair</a>
        </div>
          <div id="conteudo">
            <!--conteudo-->
          </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Quero centralizar essa pagina dentro da div id="conteudo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisei fazer algumas alterações em seu css, existem algumas coisas para ser ajustadas, como não sei se irá usar esse arquivo da formatação do formulário em outras páginas, tomei por mim manter a estrutura.

- Criei um novo estilo para o ID `conteudo`

  ```
  #conteudo{
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      top: 60px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Para definir a largura do corpo da página, onde irá ficar o conteúdo, usei javascript para definir essa largura, como está pré-definido o tamanho do menu, recuperei a largura total da página usando `screen.width` e diminuí 250 pixel(*largura do menu*). Ps: fiz o mesmo para o header.

  ```
  const conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');
  const header = document.querySelector('.header');
  conteudo.style.width = screen.width - 250;
  header.style.width = screen.width - 250;
  ```

---

- Alterei algumas coisas, segue o link do exemplo funcional completo no `jsfiddle`.

Exemplo funcional: 
https://jsfiddle.net/snvca8w1/

Comment: Resolvido amigo, muito obrigado!!!